# Perl: how to pretty-print time difference (duration)

Tags: perl, datetime, duration, datediff

How do I pretty print time duration in perl?

The only thing I could come up with so far is

```
my $interval = 1351521657387 - 1351515910623; # milliseconds
my $duration = DateTime::Duration->new(
    seconds => POSIX::floor($interval/1000) ,
    nanoseconds  => 1000000 * ($interval % 1000),
);
my $df = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
    pattern => '%Y years, %m months, %e days, ' .
               '%H hours, %M minutes, %S seconds, %N nanoseconds',
    normalize => 1,
);
print $df->format_duration($duration);
```

which results in

```
0 years, 00 months, 0 days, 01 hours, 35 minutes, 46 seconds, 764000000 nanoseconds
```

This is no good for me for the following reasons:

1. I don't want to see "*0 years*" (space waste) &c and I don't want to remove "*%Y years*" from the `pattern` (what if I do need years next time?)
2. I know in advance that my precision is only milliseconds, I don't want to see the 6 zeros in the nanoseconds part.
3. I care about prettiness/compactness/human readability much more than about precision/machine readability. I.e., I want to see something like "*1.2 years*" or "*3.22 months*" or "*7.88 days*" or "*5.7 hours*" or "*75.5 minutes*" (or "*1.26 hours*", whatever looks better to you) or "*24.7 seconds*" or "*133.7 milliseconds*" &c (similar to how **R** prints [difftime](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html))

Comment: Standard international format for times/durations is `0y 4m 7d 1h 35m 46.764s`, i.e., single-character suffixes for each component unit.

Comment: so how do I produce this? why isn't this the default?

Answer (score 3):

You could build the pattern dynamically depending on the whether or not certain values are "true".

```
...
push @pattern, '%Y years' if $duration->year;
push @pattern, '%m months' if $duration->month;
...
my $df = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
    pattern => join(', ', @pattern),
    normalize => 1,
);
print $df->format_duration($duration);
```

Comment: this only addresses my first gripe

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
sub difftime2string ($) {
  my ($x) = @_;
  ($x < 0) and return "-" . difftime2string(-$x);
  ($x < 1) and return sprintf("%.2fms",$x*1000);
  ($x < 100) and return sprintf("%.2fsec",$x);
  ($x < 6000) and return sprintf("%.2fmin",$x/60);
  ($x < 108000) and return sprintf("%.2fhrs",$x/3600);
  ($x < 400*24*3600) and return sprintf("%.2fdays",$x/(24*3600));
  return sprintf("%.2f years",$x/(365.25*24*3600));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see something like "1.2 years" or "3.22 months" or "7.88 days"

You could use the constants in [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html):

```
use Time::Seconds;
use feature qw(say);
...

$time_seconds = $interval / 1000;
if ( $time_seconds > ONE_YEAR ) {
    printf "The interval is %.2f years\n", $time_seconds / ONE_YEAR;
}
else {
if ( $time_seconds > ONE_DAY ) {
    printf "The interval is %.2f days\n", $time_seconds / ONE_DAY;
}
else { 
if ( $time_seconds > ONE_HOUR ) {
    printf "The interval is %.2f hours\n", $time_seconds / ONE_HOUR;
}
else {
    say "The interval is $time_seconds seconds";
}
```

A [switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) can also be used, but it's still marked as *experimental*;

```
use feature qw(switch say);
use Time::Seconds;

...
my $time_seconds = $interval / 1000;

for ( $time_seconds ) {
    when ( $time_seconds > ONE_YEAR ) {
        printf "The interval is %.2f years\n", $time_seconds / ONE_YEAR;
    }
    when ( $time_seconds > ONE_DAY ) {
        printf "The interval is %.2f days\n", $time_seconds / ONE_DAY;
    }
    when ( $time_seconds > ONE_HOUR ) {
        printf "The interval is %.2f hours\n", $time_seconds / ONE_HOUR;
    }
    default { say "The interval is $time_seconds seconds"; }
}
```

There may even be a way of combining everything into an array in order to have a single *Time* statement. (Untested, but you get the idea):

```
 my @times = (
    [ INTERVAL => ONE_YEAR, VALUE => "years" ],
    [ INTERVAL => ONE_DAY,  VALUE => "days"  ],
    [ INTERVAL => ONE_HOUR, VALUE => "hours" ],
);

for my $interval ( @times ) {
    if ( $time_seconds > $interval->{INTERVAL} ) {
       printf "The interval is %.2f %s\n"
          , $time_seconds / $interval->{INTERVAL}, $interval->{VALUE};
    }
}
```

Not too crazy about that. You're better off simply making a `pretty_time` subroutine to *hide* the code.

```
say pretty_time( $interval );
```